# Read a CSV in php line by line and store in a variable

Tags: php, file, csv

I want to read a CSV file in php which is like

```
203.88.0.0,203.88.31.255  
84.64.0.0,84.71.255.255  
123.63.128.0,123.63.255.255  
112.79.0.0,112.79.255.255  
1.38.0.0,1.39.255.255  
114.31.128.0,114.31.191.255
```

and get the output in a variable like:

```
MAX_checkClient_Ip('10.52.81.60|10.52.81.61', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('10.66.40.136|10.66.40.137', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('10.99.53.15|10.99.53.21', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('10.99.53.143|10.99.53.149', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('31.173.64.0|31.173.71.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('31.173.192.0|31.173.193.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('31.173.240.0|31.173.243.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('37.28.160.0|37.28.191.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('37.29.0.0|37.29.15.255', '=^')
```

Note that the firstline is not having "or"

---

```
public function create_channel()
{
                $file_handle = fopen("IP_SCRIPT.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

//print "or MAX_checkClient_Ip('".$line_of_text[0] ."|". $line_of_text[1]."', '=^')\r\n";
$str[]="or MAX_checkClient_Ip('".$line_of_text[0] ."|". $line_of_text[1]."', '=^')\r\n";

}
for($i=0;$i<count($str);$i++)
{
        echo $str[$i];
}


fclose($file_handle);

}
```

but i get output as

```
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('203.88.0.0|203.88.31.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('84.64.0.0|84.71.255.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('123.63.128.0|123.63.255.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('112.79.0.0|112.79.255.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('1.38.0.0|1.39.255.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('114.31.128.0|114.31.191.255', '=^')
or MAX_checkClient_Ip('|', '=^')
```

i dont want "or" in first line and also the last line is not needed

Comment: It's conventional to include what you've tried so far rather than just asking for a solution. Have a read of [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Tweaking your code just a little to move the handling of "or" out of the read loop and into the print loop:

```
public function create_channel()
{
     $file_handle = fopen("IP_SCRIPT.csv", "r");
     while (!feof($file_handle))
     {
         $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
         $str[]="MAX_checkClient_Ip('".$line_of_text[0] ."|". $line_of_text[1]."', '=^')";
     }
     fclose($file_handle);
     for($i=0; $i<count($str); $i++)
     {
         if ($i > 0) {
              print "or ";
         }
         print $str[$i] . "\n";
     }
}
```

@Aziz Saleh's suggestion is a good one. The entire `for` loop could be replaced by:

```
print implode("\nor ", $str) . "\n";
```

Comment: Why not have the newline in the first loop and do an implode instead of making another loop?